# $a;b;c\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Prove : $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \geq 3+\sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality

$a;b;c\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Prove : $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \geq 3+\sqrt{3}$

Thanks :)

I have proved that :
$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{bca}}=3$

And : $\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}(a+b+c)}{a+b+c}=\sqrt{3}$

!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this known lema:
$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\ge\dfrac{9(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2}$$
proof:By applying the know inequality
$$(x+y+z)^3\ge\dfrac{27}{4}(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+xyz)$$
for
$x=\dfrac{a}{b},y=\dfrac{b}{c},z=\dfrac{c}{a}$,we get
$$\left(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right)^3\ge\dfrac{27}{4}\left(\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}+1\right)$$
it suffices to prove that
$$\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}+1\ge\dfrac{108(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{(a+b+c)^6}$$
or
$$\dfrac{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)}{abc}+4\ge\dfrac{108(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{(a+b+c)^6}$$
Using now the obvious inequality $3abc(a+b+c)\le (ab+bc+ac)^2$,we have

$$\dfrac{a+b+c}{abc}=\dfrac{3(a+b+c)^2}{3abc(a+b+c)}\ge\dfrac{3(a+b+c)^2}{(ab+bc+ac)^2}$$
and hence,it is enough to check that
$$\dfrac{3(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)}{(ab+bc+ac)^2}+4\ge\dfrac{108(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{(a+b+c)^6}$$
let
$$t=\dfrac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2},1\le t<3$$
then inequality is equivalent to
$$\dfrac{54(t-1)}{(3-t)^2}+4\ge 4t^3$$
or
$$(t-1)(9-6t-8t^2+10t^3-2t^4)\ge 0$$
this is true because
$$9-6t-8t^2+10t^3-2t^4=2(3+3t-t^2)(t-1)^2+3>0$$

This lema prove by done.

so you  can let
$$x=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}\ge\dfrac{1}{3}$$
so use this lemma, it suffices to prove that
$$9x+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\ge 3+\sqrt{3}$$
let $f(x)=9x+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}},x\ge\dfrac{1}{3}$
then we have
$$f'(x)=9-\dfrac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}>0$$
so
$$f(x)\ge f(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}})=3+\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I do not seem to be able to follow the first half of your solution. Can you explain how "Using the obvious inequality, we have..." relates to the previous inequality that was to be shown?

Comment: Hello,my frend @CalvinLin,I have edit.Thank you

Comment: @math110 How do you prove the "obvious" inequality:

$$(x+y+z)^3 \ge \frac{27}{4} (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x + xyz)$$

I'm trying for couple of hours and I'm just walking in circles